# Oracle SQL Merge Statement with Conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, case

I"m relatively new to SQL, and I'm having an issue where the target table is not being updated.
I have duplicate account # (key) with different contact information in the associated columns. I’m attempting to consolidate the contact information (source) into a single row / account number with the non duplicate contact information going into (target) extended columns.

[image]

I constructed a Merge statement with a case condition to check if the data exists in the target table. If the data is not in the target table then add the information in the extended columns. The issue is that the target table doesn’t get updated.  Both Source and Target tables are similarity defined.

```
**Merge SQL- reduced query**
MERGE INTO target tgt
    USING (select accountno, cell, site, contact, email1 from (select w.accountno, w.cell, w.site, w.contact, email1, row_number() over (PARTITION BY w.accountno order by accountno desc) acct 
    from source w) inn where inn.acct =1) src 
    ON (tgt.accountno = src.accountno)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN 
        UPDATE SET
                  tgt.phone4 =  
                  CASE WHEN src.cell <> tgt.cell
                  THEN src.cell
                  END,
                  tgt.phone5 =
                  CASE WHEN src.site <> tgt.site
                  THEN src.site
                  END
```

I have validated that there is contact information in the source table for an accountno that should be added to the target table. I greatly appreciate any insight as to why the target table is not being updated.
I saw a similar question on Stack, but it didn't have a response.

Answer (score 0):

Your SRC subquery in using clause, returns just 1 random row for each accountno.
You need to aggregate them, for example using PIVOT:

```
with source(accountno, cell, site, contact) as ( --test data:
   select 1,8881234567,8881235678,8881236789 from dual union all
   select 1,8881234567,8881235678,8881236789 from dual
)
select accountno, contact, 
       r1_cell, r1_site, 
       r2_cell, r2_site
from (select s.*,row_number()over(partition by accountno order by cell) rn
      from source s
     )
pivot (
   max(cell) cell,max(site) site
    FOR rn
    IN (1 R1,2 R2)
)
```

So finally you can compare r1_cell, r1_site, r2_cell, r2_site with destination values and use required ones:

```
MERGE INTO target tgt
    USING (
            select accountno, contact, 
                   r1_cell, r1_site, 
                   r2_cell, r2_site
            from (select s.*,row_number()over(partition by accountno order by cell) rn
                  from source s
                 )
            pivot (
               max(cell) cell,max(site) site
                FOR rn
                IN (1 R1,2 R2)
            )
          ) src 
    ON (tgt.accountno = src.accountno)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN 
        UPDATE SET
                  tgt.phone4 =  
                  CASE 
                       WHEN src.r1_cell <> tgt.cell 
                          THEN src.r1_cell
                          ELSE src.r2_cell
                  END,
                  tgt.phone5 =
                  CASE WHEN src.r1_site <> tgt.site 
                     THEN src.r1_site
                     ELSE src.r2_site
                  END
/
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with regards to the logic you have used in row_numbering the rows with identical account_number.

```
MERGE 
 INTO target tgt
USING (select accountno, cell, site, contact, email1 
         from (select w.accountno, w.cell, w.site, w.contact, email1
                    , row_number() over (PARTITION BY w.accountno order by w.accountno desc) acct 
                from source w
              left join target w2
                  on w.accountno=w2.accountno
               where w2.cell is null /* get records which are not in target*/ 
              ) inn 
         where inn.acct =1
       ) src 
   ON (tgt.accountno = src.accountno)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
     UPDATE 
        SET tgt.phone4 = src.cell,
            tgt.phone5 = src.site
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, although I will have to take some time to understand the explanation so I can use it to encompass my full requirements.  I had to modify the updated code you provided to update the target table with the source table information and check tgt.phone4 is null as tgt.cell is almost never null.   Greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: I just realised that i was mistakenly updating using the alias tgt. The correct way would be as tgt.phone4 = src.cell,tgt.phone5 = src.site

Comment: np, I noticed when I tested. The gist of my issue is that I'm not ensuring that the target & source rows I'm comparing are the same. I also noticed that the target table gets updated whether or not the src data already exists in the target table. If I try a case clause in the SET, then no data gets updated. Thank you for putting me on the right path.